# Multiple condition check in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix, sh

I made a shell script to backup, view and restore installed packages in my Linux system. The script looks like:

```
#!bin/bash

echo ""
read -p "You are about to backup installed packages. Continue (y/n)?:" CONT
echo ""
if [ "$CONT" = "y" ]; then
  eval sudo pacman -Qqe | grep -vx "$(pacman -Qqm)" > packages;
else
  echo "Ok. I got you, I won't backup";
fi

    read -p "View list? (y/n):?" CONT
if [ "$CONT" = "y" ]; then
    eval xargs -a packages ;
else
    echo "Preparing to restore"
fi
echo ""
read -p "So restore list contents (y/n):?" CONT
echo ""
if [ "$CONT" = "y" ]; then
    eval sudo xargs -a packages pacman -S --needed ;
else
    echo "Ok. No packages restored!";
fi
```

This script creates a textfile containing all the package names installed in a system, then prompt the user to view the list and at last allow him to restore the packages included in the backup list.
Then, I decided to use C to do the same. I created a program like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
char ans[2];
char command[100];
printf("\nYou are about to backup installed packages. Continue (Y/N)?:");
scanf("%1s", ans);
if (strcmp(ans, "Y")==0) {
    strcpy(command, "sudo pacman -Qqe | grep -vx '$(pacman -Qqm)' > packages");
    system(command);
    printf("\nBackup done! \n");
  }
else {
    printf ("\nGot you, I won't backup \n");
  }
}
```

But this code can only give the user a single choice if he wants to back up the list or not. Due to the while loop, I get trap if I try to add another condition inside the existing while loop.

I need some help in these matters to complete the conditions below. 
How do one give a user some other choices such as :

1) View the backup list?   2) Restore the packages that backup list contains?

An example will be very helpful :))

Comment: `#!b1n/bash` -->> `#!/bin/bash`, for a start ...

Comment: OT: Either change `scanf("%c", &ans);` to be `scanf("%1s", ans);` or change `(strcmp(ans, "Y")==0)` to be `(ans[0] == 'Y')` (mind the single quotes vs. double quotes).

Comment: Thank you guys for correcting my mistake. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Neither of the uses of `eval` in your shell script call for it. Using `eval` [creates substantial security risks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) -- it should only be used when your script can't possibly be written without it, and that's certainly not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct one would be

```
if(scanf("%1s",ans)!=1){
   // error handle
}
```

This will make you use it properly in the `strcmp` function.

Or you can do this

```
if(scanf("%c",&ans[0])!=1){
   // error handle
}
ans[1]=0;
```

Then you can use it in `strcmp` or simply you can use

```
if(ans[0]=='Y'){
   ...
}
```

The return value of `scanf` is checked to know whether the `scanf` call is successful or not.

Also instead of `strcpy` use `sprintf` or similar so that you won't run into buffer overrun. Here you know the length but in many siatuations you won't - it is good and safe to `sprintf` then.

If you enable warning in compiler then you will see type mismatch warning. Something like

```
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[2]' [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%s",&ans);
     ^
```

Try to compile the code with `-Wall -Werror` flags enabled.

Comment: Oh that was very useful advice :)

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the while loop, I get trap if I try to add another condition inside the existing while loop.

I don't exactly get what you say there (I can see no `while` loops in there), but here goes my answer. You may use similar if-else constructs to prompt the user to list backups and to restore from them. Your final program will look something like:

```
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char ans;    //You need only a char variable, not an array

    printf("\nYou are about to backup installed packages. Continue (Y/N)?:");
    scanf(" %c", &ans);
    if (toupper(ans) == 'Y') {
        system("sudo pacman -Qqe | grep -vx '$(pacman -Qqm)' > packages");
        printf("\nBackup done! \n");
    }
    else
        printf ("\nGot you, I won't backup \n");

    printf("\nView list? (y/n) ");
    scanf(" %c",&ans);
    if(toupper(ans) == 'Y')
        system("xargs -a packages");

    printf("\nSo restore listed contents? (y/n) ");
    scanf(" %c",&ans);
    if(toupper(ans) == 'Y')
        system("sudo xargs -a packages pacman -S --needed");
    else
        printf("\nOK, no packages restored.");
}
```

Or else, you may use a menu-based approach to solve the problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void backup(){
    system("sudo pacman -Qqe | grep -vx \"$(pacman -Qqm)\" > packages");
    printf("\nBackup done!");
}

void list(){
    printf("\nHere comes the listing:\n");
    system("xargs -a packages");
}

void restore(){
    system("sudo xargs -a packages pacman -S --needed");
    printf("\nRestore done!");
}

int main(){
    char choice;
    do{
        printf("\nSelect any action from the following:\n\
        1. Backup packages\n\
        2. List packages\n\
        3. Restore packages\n\
        4. Exit\
    >>> ");
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case '1': backup();
                  break;
            case '2': list();
                  break;
            case '3': restore();
                  break;
            default : printf("\nIllegal choice!");
        }
    }while(choice!='4');    
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**:
Fixed `scanf()` bug, refer: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/

Comment: Hoho. This menu-driven design looks so pro. I didn't know that technique :)) Thanks a lot, Mukesh :))

Comment: Not sure what caused this in your code: [Screenshot View](https://imgur.com/a/jUCTt)

Comment: @SudarshanKakoty Fixed the bug (added a few whitespaces in my program :P It doesn't look like edited) refer to the link in my edit notice

Comment: Lol. Okay. I got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    char ans[2];
    char command[100];
    printf("\nYou are about to backup installed packages. Continue? (Y/N):");
    scanf("%1s", ans);
    if(ans[0]=='Y'|| ans[0]=='y') {
        sprintf(command, "sudo pacman -Qqe | grep -vx '$(pacman -Qqm)' > packages");
        system(command);
        printf("\nBackup done! \n");
    }
    if(ans[0]=='N'|| ans[0]=='n') {
        printf ("\nOk. Got you, I won't backup \n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);     
    }

    printf ("\nView list? (Y/N):\n");
    scanf("%1s", ans);
    if(ans[0]=='Y'|| ans[0]=='y') {
    sprintf(command, "xargs -a packages");
        system(command);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("\nPreparing to restore \n");
    }
    printf ("So restore list contents? (Y/N):");
    scanf("%1s", ans);
    if(ans[0]=='Y' || ans[0]=='y'){
        sprintf(command, "sudo xargs -a packages pacman -S --needed");
        system(command);
        }
        else {
            printf ("\nOk. No packages restored!\n");
        }
}
```